# How to hide a masterpage div when displayed in a SharePoint dialog window

Tags: master-page, custom

I have a sharepoint 2013 portal. I have customized the masterpage by adding a div with a background image. How can I fix this? I only would like to show this header image in the header of the masterpage. Not in popups.

Here is some code snippet where you can see my div with background image:

```
<span id="ms-help">
    <SharePoint:ThemedClusteredHoverImage
        runat="server"
        ID="TopHelpLink"
        ThemeKey="spintl"
        TouchMode="true"
        TouchModeWidth="30"
        TouchModeHeight="30"
        TouchModePaddingTop="7"
        TouchModePaddingRight="7"
        TouchModePaddingBottom="7"
        TouchModePaddingLeft="7"
        ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/~lcid/images/spintl.png"
        Width="16"
        Height="16"
        OffsetX="19"
        OffsetY="1"
        HoverOffsetX="1"
        HoverOffsetY="1"
        NavigateUrl="#"
        onclick="TopHelpButtonClick('HelpHome',event);return false"
        AlternateText="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_text%>"
        AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_accesskey%>"
        ToolTip="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_text%>" />
</span>
                </div>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="background-image:url('/Style%20Library/lfr/header.jpg');background-position:left; background-repeat:repeat-x;height:147px;"></div>
        <div id="ms-hcTest"></div>
        <div id="s4-ribbonrow">
        <div id="globalNavBox" class="noindex">
<div id="ribbonBox">
    <div id="s4-ribboncont">
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the `ms-dialogHidden` class to your outer div, it will hide the content in dialogs:

```
<div class="ms-dialogHidden" style="background-image:url('/Style%20Library/lfr/header.jpg');background-position:left; background-repeat:repeat-x;height:147px;"></div>
```

For more, see here: http://ericoverfield.com/sharepoint-2013-tricks-hide-elements-in-dialogs/

Comment: In 2010 it was `s4-notdlg`. The rule, IIRC, is `.ms-dialog .s4-notdlg { display: none !important; }`